# Why isn't CRM logging in under my logged in credentials?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9, dynamics-crm

Good morning.  For some reason, I am not being logged into our on-premise CRM application with my credentials, rather, I am being logged in as a separate, admin user.  I have checked the site's security zone settings, they are correct and are passing credentials; I have tried an IE reset, same result; I have tried running IE as my user but it still logs into CRM as the admin user.  Any ideas?

Comment: Upon further investigation, it seems as though CRM is passing the incorrect SID to the CRM database when it attempts to match my windows credentials with CRM user credentials.

Comment: Are you logged in as an admin user or a normal user?

Comment: I am logged into windows as my, normal user.  When I open IE, and navigate to CRM, I expect it to pass my credentials but it does not, it passes the credentials of the admin user

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question.  My user is in the administrators group of my local PC.

Comment: I assume you're in some kind of domain environment? Are you in any of the administrative groups in the domain as well? Your local admin account is only meaningful on your own computer unless you happen to have an account with the same user name and password on your remote server.

Comment: I am not sure that whether or not my account is in administrative groups is related to my initial problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure of the why but the solution to this issue was to re-create my local, Win 7 profile.  After I did this, CRM would log me in with the correct credentials.